# different behavior of parallel when input is from STDIN

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am using the GNU parallel tool. I have an input file in.txt the looks like this:

```
export MY_ENV=$1 && echo hi: $MY_ENV
export MY_ENV=$1 && echo hi: $MY_ENV
export MY_ENV=$1 && echo hi: $MY_ENV
export MY_ENV=$1 && echo hi: $MY_ENV
export MY_ENV=$1 && echo hi: $MY_ENV
export MY_ENV=$1 && echo hi: $MY_ENV
```

I use this command (case 1) to invoke parallel:

```
parallel -j 4 -a in.txt  --link ::: 11 22 33 44
```

which (as expected) results in this output:

```
hi: 11
hi: 22
hi: 33
hi: 44
hi: 11
hi: 22
```

However when i try to send the input via STDIN using the command below (case 2) I get different behavior. In other words this command:

```
cat in.txt | parallel -j 4  --link ::: 11 22 33 44
```

results in this error message:

```
/bin/bash: 11: command not found
/bin/bash: 22: command not found
/bin/bash: 33: command not found
/bin/bash: 44: command not found
```

Shouldn't the behavior be identical? How can I invoke the parallel program so that when the input is via STDIN I get the same output as in case 1 above?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat in.txt | parallel -j 4 -a - --link ::: 11 22 33 44
```

or

```
cat in.txt | parallel -j 4 --link :::: - ::: 11 22 33 44
```

or

```
cat in.txt | parallel -j 4 :::: - :::+ 11 22 33 44
```

See details on https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014 (section 4.2).